# how to find out r programming to calculate average error?

Tags: r

I want to do 10-fold cross validation in r coding to calculate average error rate = ycap-y(y=xbeta) and for example 0-10 testing set and 90-100 training 11-20 testing and 0-10 ,21-100 training 21-31 testing and 0-20,31-100 training?

how to write r code for this ?

IN  y=xm *beta

how  can i substitute  both training and testing methods  in xm?and  how  the  loop will run  please  anyone write  r code  for this  without  using  lm or glm function ?

```
rm(list=ls())
data1 <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=T)
n = nrow(data1)
m = ncol(data1)
x=data1[-m]
y=data1[m]
xm = ncol(x)
ym = n/10
x<-(matrix(unlist(x),ncol=xm, byrow=F))
y<-matrix(unlist(y),ncol=1,byrow=F)
a=1
prediction <- c()
for(j in 1:12)
{
  p <- c(a)
  for (i in 1:9)
  {
    p <- append(p, a+i)
  }
  a=p[10]+1
  p <- as.integer(p)
  xtrain <- x[-p,]
  xtest <- x[p,]
  ytrain <- y[-p]
  ytest <- y[p]
  beta=solve(t(xtrain)%*%xtrain)%*%t(xtrain)%*%ytrain
  beta=solve(t(xtest)%*%xtest)%*%t(xtest)%*%ytest
  }
ycap=xtest %*% beta
```

IN this  code  how to find out  the testset  and find beta and to calculate average error?